# Angular 2 - Turn countdown

Tags: angular

My Angular 2 app allow players to battle each other.

Each player can play in his own turn, and each turn has a limit of **60 seconds**.

I'm trying to make a 60 seconds countdown with server data, **without** using computer clock (which may be missleading when the players using different timezone or clock settings).

This is the last turn time: `this.future = new Date(this.battleData.last_turn_time);`

That's my countdown method which has 2 problems:

1. Using computer time.. (Why I should NOT use it explained above)
2. Updates every 3 seconds (when I execute API CALL, which is every 3 seconds).

`countDown()
       {

           //Countdown
                this.future = new Date(this.battleData.last_turn_time);`

```
           let date1 = Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/1000);
           let date2 =  Math.floor(this.future.getTime()/1000)+(this.TURN_TIME);
            this.diff = date2 - date1;
            this.secondsLeft = this.diff;

}
```

Comment: a good point should be using `sockets`... the server has to send notification when: 1. you can play, 2. when your playing time is end, 3. ecc... by the way, I think you need server push notifications

Comment: My app based on Laravel and Angular 2. I really have no idea how to start with sockets |:

Comment: I've not expertise on Laravel, but, google is displaying many good results... try to find something with `laravel` and `socket.io` (which is a socket library)... https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/step-by-step-guide-to-installing-socketio-and-broadcasting-events-with-laravel-51